# Get an Array from HashSet in c# with operator [..]

Tags: c#, range, operator-keyword, hashset, indexer

Are these range operator and indexer? I have never seen them used like this `[..h]`.
Line 6 in this code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    HashSet<int> h=new(a);
        /// do somethings on HashSet
    WriteArray([..h]);
}

static void WriteArray(int[] a)
{
    foreach(var n in a)
    {
        Console.Write($"{n} ");
    }
}
```

What operator are used in `[..h]` ?
Can you recommend a reference to study these operators or the method used?

Comment: `[]` is an array initializer and the `..` is the `list all operator`. [..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/), [Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/arrays)

Comment: Check out what is [new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-12#collection-expressions) in c# 12

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `list all operator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[..h]` is a [collection expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions), basically a concise syntax to create collections, arrays, and spans. The things inside the `[` and `]` are the collection's elements, e.g.

```
List<int> x = [1,2,3];
// basically:
// var x = new List<int> { 1,2,3 };
```

Since this is passed to a parameter expecting `int[]`, `[..h]` represents an `int[]`. What does this array contain then? What is `..h`? In a collection expression, `..` can be prefixed to another collection to "[spread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions#spread-element)" that collection's elements.

Since `h` contains the numbers 1 to 9, this is basically `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, though since a `HashSet` is not ordered, the order of the elements may be different.

Usually `..` is used when there are other elements/collections you want to put in the collection expression, as the example from the documentation shows:

```
string[] vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"];
string[] consonants = ["b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m",
                       "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "v", "w", "x", "z"];
string[] alphabet = [.. vowels, .. consonants, "y"];
```

So `[..h]` is rather a odd use of collection expressions. It would be more readable to use `h.ToArray()` instead.